# Get block hash from a receipt id in Near blockchain localnet

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol, near-api-js

On sending the function call txn using `near-api-js`, I only receive receipt id (as shown in the logs) and from the docs , it looks like I cannot get the block hash just from receipt id.
How can I get the block hash or timestamp of a txn from receipt id ?
Is it possible to get the txn id from receipt id ?

```
const contract = new Contract(account, 'counter.test.near', {
    viewMethods: ['getCount'],
    changeMethods: ['increase', 'decrease'],
  });
 await contract.increase({
          args: {},
          gas: '30000000000000',
          amount: '0',
        })
```

`Receipt: BBwboTVFj2S2PM5abVkyMCCZGqUvJhQNksK7JzZdqaNu`